# reset instance variable for a servlet class for each incoming request

Tags: java, variables, servlets, instance

I ran into a situation where value of counter is keep increasing while handling incoming http request rather than it sets to 0. It acts like class variable instead of an instance variable. I wonder it is b/c once an instance of the Foo class is created for the first time, then for the next round of request a thread is created for the same instance of it. It seems like meaningless to have "counter" variable as an instance variable. I should make it as a local variable within doPost method if I want to reset it back to zero once process of incoming data is completed for the next round of incoming request. Is there better way to handle this situation as part of class variable?

```
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    private int counter = 0; 

    protected void doPost(.....) throws Exception {
        // process incoming request data
        // increment counter by one
        counter++;
        ......
    }
 }
```

Comment: The servlet spec explicitly recommends that servlets be stateless to avoid this issue. Why are you maintaining a counter in the first place? This sounds like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @Tom G: I didn't understand that the meaning behind of stateless for the servlet class. Now I do. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you're going to achieve, but in general you should avoid keeping any state in servlet objects. Use request.getAttribute(), request.setAttribute(), request.getSession().getAttribute() or request.getSession().setAttribute(). Alternatively you can use request scoped or session scoped beans in eg jsf or spring.